# Accessing Discogs API from PHP

Tags: php, json, discogs-api

I'm trying to get release data in JSON format via Discogs API, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? This code works well with other URLs.

```
<?php 
$opts = array('http' => array('method' => 'GET',
'header' => 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,
deflate\r\nUser-Agent: TheVinylCrate/1.0 +http://www.hazadus.net\r\n')); 

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 

echo file_get_contents('http://api.discogs.com/releases/4976693', false, $context); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents(('http://api.discogs.com/releases/4976693'), false); 
?>
```

This will work. You don't need to add any option.

Comment: It works with any other URL, but not with Discogs API... It is said in Discogs API manual http://www.discogs.com/developers/accessing.html#required-headers that I must set proper "User-Agent" string in order to get data from their server. But it doesn't help, too.

Comment: <?php
$url = 'http://api.discogs.com/releases/4976693';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'TheVinylCrate/1.0 +http://www.hazadus.net');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
?>

I found that somewhere, seems the author is the owner of hazadus.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP and want to connect to the Discogs API you probably want to use the client I wrote:
https://github.com/ricbra/php-discogs-api